# What are the alternate ways to host a chrome extension other than developer dashboard

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, chrome-web-store

I have built and hosted chrome extension in chrome webstore through developer dashboard. With the recent announcement in https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/migrating, it is mentioned that Chrome will be removing support for Chrome Apps on Windows, Mac, and Linux. 
In view of the latest announcements I have few questions.

1.Will chrome be removing chrome extension support in near future?

2.Does it allow/accept new extensions to be published in Webstore?

3.Is there any other alternative way of publishing a new extension to Webstore without using the developer dashboard.

Please guide.

Answer (score 1):

1. No, support is ongoing with no end planned.
2. Yes, new extensions are allowed to be published to the web store.
3. There is not an alternative publishing platform. In previous years Google has significantly increased security measures to make the web store the source for installations. However you can potentially host your code on a platform such as GitHub and have users download/install it using Developer mode.